# Why are CSS-inlined (base64-encoded) webfonts rendered with a delay?

Tags: html, css, browser, base64, webfonts

Twitter started using a WOFF webfont ([screenshot](https://twitter.com/simevidas/status/472541998252294145)). This font is base64-encoded and inlined in a CSS file which is `<link>`ed inside the `<head>`.

Now, if I understand correctly, `<link>`ed CSS style sheets are render-blocking, i.e. browsers will not render the page until they've fetched/parsed its external CSS files.

In this case, when visiting Twitter, the browser should load the CSS file containing the webfont and then render the page **with that webfont**. However, I've performed a test (on empty cache/browser history) in Chrome/Windows, and the webfont is displayed **with a delay**: The text on the page is first rendered using the default `sans-serif` font of the OS, and then, after a few seconds, the webfont "kicks in" and replaces the system font.

**See here:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yt9UXHmNofA (the switch happens at the 6 sec mark)

Why is this happening? Why is Chrome not displaying the webfont on the first render? Could it be that the base64 decoding happens asynchronously?

Comment: Yeah, some things are asynchronous. Fonts, images, iframes, that sort of stuff.

Comment: @bjb568 you're missing the point a bit. The font is "loaded" through the render-blocking CSS, OP wants to know it takes several seconds after the font is already downloaded to be rendered in the page.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Because it's asynchronous.

Comment: @bjb568 asynchronous resources are displayed as soon as (or soon after) they are available. In this case, the font's data is available before the initial render. Chrome's hard-refresh displays the webfont right in the initial render, while a page load with actual empty cache takes up to **several** seconds to render the webfont -- that is a huge, seemingly unexplainable, discrepancy which should not exist. You could say that in the former case the font is rendered asynchronously before the initial render due to in-memory cache or something, but it doesn't explain the other case where (cont)

Comment: @bjb568 it takes several seconds to render the font after its data is already available, which IMO seems more like a browser bug.

Comment: As a random guess, assuming that webfont decoding/rendering is always pushed to an asynchronous stack for the sake of a simpler implementation, this could be the result of a race condition and, if the initial render completes before the font decoding, Blink throttles webfont rendering in order to reduce reflows. Well, this is just a rather far-fetched theory, it is probably better to look up the source than make up theories.

Comment: Related: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=351386

Comment: Perhaps it is worth opening a Chromium issue to discuss this? The people there surely knows more about the implementation details than us.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I've updated my question. Turns out, only the first 5 style sheets are render-blocking in Chrome on empty cache.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas woah, that's some nice detective work! Although, my Chrome does not delay any of the stylesheet files for some reason. Maybe it is based on connection speed?

Comment: Weird, webpagetest and your Chrome delays the 6th stylesheet, but [mine does not](http://i.imgur.com/XrBUpc5.jpg). This is most likely the reason why it was so hard for me to reproduce the issue when we first chatted.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I've cleared the browsing data before performing the test. I've also made sure not to type the URL into the address bar (instead I would quickly paste the URL and press ENTER) - Chrome has an aggressive pre-fetching strategy, so if you type the URL and wait for 1-2 seconds, Chrome might already fetch the page in the background.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yeah, I know Chrome does DNS resolution in the background, I'll clear my browsing data and try again as you've done.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas okay this is weird, I'm only seeing 4 stylesheets in the Network tab now, tested on both stable and Canary Chrome with empty cache. Can you test again and see if I'm going crazy or something? **Edit:** Oh never mind, when you're logged out it injects 2 more stylesheets. Thus you must be logged out to perform this test.

Comment: Oh you're right, I can [reproduce it](http://i.imgur.com/GeSSE8y.png). This discrepancy between hard refresh and actual no cache is bothering me more than it should.

Comment: BUT WAIT! If we take a closer look at the image, the gotham stylesheet seems to be script-injected! Now at the same time it makes sense why the stylesheet loading is non-blocking, but I'm perplexed about what logic does Twitter use to decide whether to delay that stylesheet?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas try the same test as you did, empty cache, new window, but now with the URL `view-source:https://twitter.com/simevidas` -- the `gotham-narrow-v3.css` stylesheet won't be in the markup, it is script injected! Thus it is not blocking. Hah, that is some twitter troll code.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Mind blown. When I view `view-source:https://twitter.com/simevidas` *after* loading the page, it is **exactly one line longer** and the `<link>` with the font is indeed injected. How the hell are they injecting into the HTML source?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas probably from the back-end. Oh, if you mean how they determine whether to inject it in the markup, I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Probably, some HTTP request header is triggering it. Since the font is WOFF, they most likely have UA detection on the server.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas well, the UA should be the same independent of cache. Maybe it is a cookie?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas There's a ["goth" cookie](http://i.imgur.com/XHFpy4m.png) which is set in the first load. Delete it and the page will render without the stylesheet. So I believe they're doing the detection client-side and storing the result in a cookie.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas as for how they "inject" it in the markup when you view-source, I can only assume that view-source does a new request, thus sending the `goth` cookie which is set when you first open the page.

Comment: So, if that's enough, maybe edit the question with this reasoning and we vote to close for being non-repro? All this Twitter debugging seems to be a bit too localized and unlikely to help anyone heh (although it was fun `:)`).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, exactly. The first request doesn't have the style sheet. It is dynamically injected and the cookie is set. When trying to view-source, a new request is made and you get a different source (with the 6. <link>). LOL

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I have to finish work and go to bed now :) I'll edit tomorrow.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas it was a fun debugging session. G'night. `=]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(putting this together into an answer so people don't have to read through the endless comments)

Unexpectedly, this is unrelated to the browser, rather it is about how Twitter includes the style sheet.

Basically, a cookie named "goth" determines whether the font style sheet is injected in a blocking or non-﻿blocking  way.

### In-depth explanation

In the first load (without cookies) of a Twitter page, the font style sheet is asynchronously injected (that is, in a non-﻿blocking way) and a [cookie named "goth" is set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu4LI.png)¹.

In subsequent requests which send the `goth` cookie, the font style sheet is served in a blocking way, in the form of a `<link rel="stylesheet">` in the `<head>` of the document.

To see this by yourself, follow these simple instructions:

- In Chrome, open `view-source:https://twitter.com/simevidas`
- Open the DevTools (F12) -> "Resources" tab -> Cookies -> twitter.com, delete the [`goth` cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu4LI.png).
- Hit reload (F5). As your request headers did not include a `goth` cookie, the font style sheet (`gotham-narrow-v3.css`) is not present in the document's `head`, rather it is in a hidden HTML-encoded JSON string ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpgBu.png)). It will be injected asynchronously via JavaScript later.
- Check your cookies in the DevTools Resources tab again -- just reloading the view-source page was enough to set the `goth` cookie again for me, but in case you don't have the `goth` cookie just open a Twitter page.
- Now with the `goth` cookie set, reload the view-source page again. You will notice that the font style sheet (`gotham-narrow-v3.css`) is now included via a `<link rel="stylesheet">` inside the document's head ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmlkR.png)). This one is loaded before the first render, as `<link>`ed CSS style sheets are render-blocking.

And of course, hard-refreshing (Ctrl/Cmd+F5) will still send the cookies and load the font style sheet in the blocking manner.

---

¹: Initially, I believed this was supposed to be some sort of lazy loading with feature detection, but I've tested it on Firefox 3.5 (which does not support `WOFF` webfonts) and Firefox 3.0.13 (which does not support webfonts at all) and both are having the `goth` cookie being set.

As the cookie is actually a session cookie (is discarded once the browser is closed), it is more plausible that the first asynchronous-injection is done to speed up the first render, and subsequent requests assume that the font style sheet is already cached and inserts it in a blocking way to prevent flash-of-unwebfont'ed-content (a more specific form of [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) which I just made up).

I haven't made it through the minified JS to be sure of that, but feel free to edit this answer or comment if you manage to.

---

And yes, this is highly localized topic which probably won't help many people, I've just decided to put it all together in a clear and concise answer just so those who are interested in this topic don't have to venture into the endless comments in the question.

Comment: Good response. Very similar approach is described here, in  https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-events.html